# How do I detect when an HTML5 datepicker is closed?

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

## Background

I am building a date range picker which uses two HTML `type="date"` input elements:

[image]

I can detect when the datepicker is closed if the user selects a different date than was previously selected, using the `change` event. However, if the use selects the same date, the input value doesn't change, and Firefox doesn't fire the `change` event, or the `input` event.

## Example Code

```js
var dateInput = document.querySelector('[name="dateBegin"]');
var debugEl = document.querySelector('#debug');

dateInput.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  debugEl.innerHTML += '<br>Event fired: click';    
});

dateInput.addEventListener('input', function(event){
  debugEl.innerHTML += '<br>Event fired: input'; 
});

dateInput.addEventListener('change', function(event){
  debugEl.innerHTML += '<br>Event fired: change'; 
});
```

```html
<input type="date" name="dateBegin">
<div id="debug"></div>
```

## Question

Is there a way to detect when the HTML datepicker is closed due to user interaction, even if the value of the input doesn't change?

Comment: It seems click event is working as you expect!!!

Comment: It works for me aswell.

Comment: use blur event?

Comment: About the nearest thing would be when the user moves away from the field and it loses focus (I.e. the blue event). Do you need to know about it while the box is still focussed? What do you actually want to do when you've detected this?

Comment: @Adyson ... the purpose here is that I'm building a date range picker that lives in a custom popup/overlay. When either the date begin or date end inputs are changed, the `change` event causes the popup/overlay to be hidden. However, I noticed that if the user selects the same date, it doesn't fire `change`, so the popup/overlay stays showing, with no good way to figure out why.

Comment: The click event doesn't work *when the calendar is closed*! It's fired when somebody *click* in the box, so when *opening* the calendar.

Comment: @AndyMercer I know of no way to do this with an HTML `date` element. If you can switch to a jQuery [`DatePicker`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) object, you can use its [`onClose`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) event.

Comment: For overlay effect, please refer [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date]. You should find the details of style you want to change.

Comment: The click event for date input is broken for Chrome at the moment (version 106.0.5249.119). A [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1384491) has been filed for the same.